# Want to store XML in SQL Server 2014 table and apply select on same

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

Having data in the for of XML and I want to store that XML in a SQL Server table. I have created a column of datatype `xml` and tried to store my XML data in that newly created column, but I get an error on `INSERT`:

> The data type 'xml' used in the VALUE method is invalid.

This is the `Insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO UserDeatailtbl(RoleXml)
    SELECT Y.ID.value('./RoleXml[1]', 'XML') 
    FROM @UserDetailsXML.nodes('UserDetails/UserDetailsRow') AS Y(ID)
```

Comment: It would help tp provide a reduced example of your XML. **Assumption:** There is a bigger XML including many `<UserDetailsRow>` nodes and you try to create one row per each. **Wild guess:** You do not want to store the XML as XML but rather want to read the included values into your table's columns? Please state the import (your XML) and the expected result.

Comment: @Shnugo Its a nested Xml. Outer XMl having two nodes that i am storing in table but 3rd node is XML that i want to store as it is in table.

Comment: Without knowing your XML it is guessing... Does your table include just one single column `RoleXml`? What does *outer XML* mean? What does *storing in table* mean? If @marc_s answer does not help you out, please provide more details...

Comment: @Shnugo the given solution is the exact what i was looking for. I am getting desired output by given solution.

Comment: In this case you should accept the answer (click the check below the vote counter). You are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. Votes and acceptance are different actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `.query()` operator instead of `.value()` - like this:

```
INSERT INTO UserDetailtbl(RoleXml)
    SELECT ID.query('.') 
    FROM @UserDetailsXML.nodes('UserDetails/UserDetailsRow/RoleXml') AS Y(ID)
```

Maybe that'll work, since the `.query()` operator is returning an XML fragment by definition.

If it doesn't work, we'll need to know more about your XML structure - can you show us an example of your XML stored in the `@UserDetailsXML` variable? Which part of that do you want to insert into `UserDetailTbl.RoleXml`?

Comment: solution given by you resolved my problem and I got exact output what I required :)

Comment: @SwapnaliHadawale: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.